# Como actualizar un campo Id

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Tengo una información migrada a una tabla necesito que en ese campo crearle un número que comience desde el 16 y termine hasta el ultimo registro que hay en esa columna.

[image: productos]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero te recomiendo probar esto en una copia de tus datos

Te muestro el siguiente ejemplo y como es que se me ocurrió para resolverlo

**CREO UNA TABLA CON LA SIGUIENTE ESTRUCTURA**

```
CREATE TABLE demo(
 id INT,
 name varchar(20)
);
```

**INSERTO UNA SERIE DE DATOS DONDE COMO NOTO TENGO UN ID REPETIDO SIMILAR A TU ESCENARIO**

```
insert into demo(id, name)
values
(1, 'alfa'),
(1, 'beta'),
(1, 'gama'),
(1, 'delta'),
(1, 'teta');
```

**SI AHORA HAGO UN SELECT**

```
select * from demo;
```

**OBTENGO LOS SIGUIENTES DATOS**

```
id  name
1   alfa
1   beta
1   gama
1   delta
1   teta
```

**AHORA MEDIANTE LA DECLARACIÓN DE UNA VARIABLE QUE USARÉ COMO CONTADOR PARA INCREMENTAR EL VALOR**

> Para inicializar el `counter`, establezco que su valor se incremente en
>   1 partiendo del número 15 cuando el id sea igual a 1, que para el caso
>   de mi ejemplo todos los registros tienen ese id y por lo tanto se
>   aplicaría a cada registro

```
DECLARE @counter INT = 15;

UPDATE demo SET id = @counter, @counter = @counter + 1 WHERE id = 1;
```

**HAGO UN NUEVO SELECT**

```
select * from demo;
```

**EL RESULTADO QUE OBTENDRÍA**

```
id  name
16  alfa
17  beta
18  gama
19  delta
20  teta
```

Es una aproximación espero te sirva

Answer (score 0):

en mi caso la columna id tiene diferentes valores y lo que quiero es:

que el primer valor empiece en 5000 y el resto delos valores se incremente en 1.

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/379204)